# angularjs grid list top alignment

Tags: css, angularjs

I am trying top align the table within my grid list so all the tables across the rows line up. 
I am using layout="column" layout-align="start center"> base on https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/alignment#layout-row-layout-align-center-center.
However, it is not still not working, the tables are center align rather than top align. 
Any suggestion?

```
<md-content>
    <md-grid-list md-cols="3" md-gutter="1em" md-row-height="2:1" >
        <md-grid-tile ng-repeat="user in users"  class="curvetable2" layout="column" layout-align="start center">
            <md-grid-tile-header class="curvetable3" >
                <h3><a style="color:white" ng-click="userCompletedCoursesDisplay(user.username, user.name)">{{user.name}}</a> <a ng-if="user.ismanager == 'yes'" style="color:#ffff99" ng-click="directManager(user.username, user.name)"> Manager - View Team</a></h3>
            </md-grid-tile-header>
            <div style="width:90%;">
                </br></br>
                <table style="width:100%;" >                
                    <tr ng-repeat="course in user.course">
                        <td valign="top"><a ng-click="courseDisplay(course.id, user.username, 'organization')">{{course.name}}</a></td>
                        <td valign="top">{{course.date}} </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-if="user.more==true">
                        <td valign="top"><a ng-click="userCompletedCoursesDisplay(user.username, user.name)">Additional Courses</a></td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
            </div>
        </md-grid-tile>
    </md-grid-list>
</md-content>
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'not working' ?

Comment: the tables are still center align